# OpenGL ES draws a black texture

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es-2.0

The below code is used in my Android OpenGL-ES game to draw a textured rectangle on the screen. The only problem is that instead of the loaded PNG a black texture is drawn on the rectangle.

AssetManager.cpp (Loads the file from the file system into memory)

```
    void AssetManager::Retrieve() {
    auto file = File("spritesheet_full.png");

    if (!file.Open()) {
        PrintVerbose("Woops");
    }
    unsigned char dataA[file.Length()];
    size_t position = 0;

    file.Read(dataA, file.Length(), position);

    auto data = std::vector<unsigned char>(dataA, dataA + file.Length());

    auto png = PNG(data);

    Texture::Header textureHeader;
    textureHeader.width = png.getWidth();
    textureHeader.height = png.getHeight();
    textureHeader.bytesPerPixel = 4;
    textureHeader.dataSize = textureHeader.width * textureHeader.height
            * textureHeader.bytesPerPixel;

    texture.SetData(textureHeader, png.getData());
    texture.Init();
}
```

PNG.cpp (Takes the data read and decodes it into raw image data. I assume this part works because the read width and height is correct. `image` is defined as `unsigned char* image`)

```
    PNG::PNG(std::vector<unsigned char> data)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> rawImage;

    lodepng::decode(rawImage, width, height, data);

    image = new unsigned char[width *  height* 4];

    for(int i = 0; i < width * height * 4; i++)
    {
        image[i] = rawImage[i];
    }
}
```

Texture.cpp (Contains the image data, and links it with OpenGL)

```
Texture::Texture() :
        id(GL_INVALID_VALUE) {

}

Texture::~Texture() {

}

void Texture::SetData(Texture::Header& header, void* pImageData) {
    headerData = header;
    imageData = pImageData;
}

void Texture::Init() {
    GLint packBits = 4;
    GLint internalFormat = GL_RGBA;
    GLenum format = GL_RGBA;
    switch (headerData.bytesPerPixel) {
    case 1: {
        packBits = 1;
        internalFormat = GL_ALPHA;
        format = GL_ALPHA;
    }
        break;
    };

    glGenTextures(1, &id);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, packBits);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, headerData.width,
            headerData.height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
}
```

TextureShader.cpp (Texture is linked to the shader, throuh a simple getter. `TextureShader::Setup` is then called by the Renderer)

```
TextureShader::TextureShader() :
        texture(NULL) {
    vertexShaderCode = "attribute vec2 position;        \n"
            "attribute vec2 a_texCoord;         \n"
            "varying   vec2 v_texCoord;         \n"
            "uniform mat4 projView; \n"
            "uniform mat4 transformMatrix; \n"
            "uniform mat4 cameraTransform; \n"
            "void main(){                       \n"
            "     gl_Position = projView * (cameraTransform * (transformMatrix * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0)));    \n"
            "    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;       \n"
            "}                                  \n";

    fragmentShaderCode = "precision highp float;                                \n"
            "varying vec2 v_texCoord;                               \n"
            "uniform sampler2D s_texture;                           \n"
            "void main(){                                           \n"
            "    gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_texture, v_texCoord);   \n"
            "}                                                      \n";
}

TextureShader::~TextureShader() {

}

void TextureShader::Link() {
    Shader::Link();

    this->positionAttributeHandle = glGetAttribLocation(programId, "position");
    this->texCoordAttributeHandle = glGetAttribLocation(programId, "a_texCoord");
    this->samplerHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "s_texture");
    this->projectionViewUniformHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "projView");
    this->transformationUniformHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "transformMatrix");
    this->cameraTransformUniformHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "cameraTransform");
}

void TextureShader::Setup(Renderable* renderable, GLfloat* cameraTransform,
        GLfloat* projectionView) {

    Geometry* pGeometry = renderable->GetGeometry();
    if (pGeometry && texture) {
        Shader::Setup(renderable, cameraTransform, projectionView);

        glActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture->GetId());
        glUniform1i(samplerHandle, 0);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionViewUniformHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, projectionView);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(transformationUniformHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, renderable->GetTransform()->GetTranslateMatrix());
        glUniformMatrix4fv(cameraTransformUniformHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, cameraTransform);

        glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeHandle,
                pGeometry->GetNumVertexPositionElements(), GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                pGeometry->GetVertexStride(), pGeometry->GetVertexBuffer());
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeHandle);

        glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordAttributeHandle,
                pGeometry->GetNumTexCoordElements(), GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                pGeometry->GetTextStride(),
                pGeometry->GetTextureCoordinates());

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordAttributeHandle);
    }
}
```

Renderer.cpp (Maintains the renderable entities and renders them)

```
void Renderer::Init()
{
    // initialize OpenGL ES and EGL

    /*
     * Here specify the attributes of the desired configuration.
     * Below, we select an EGLConfig with at least 8 bits per color
     * component compatible with on-screen windows
     */
    const EGLint attribs[] =
    { EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT, EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
            EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8, EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8, EGL_RED_SIZE, 8, EGL_NONE };

    EGLint format;
    EGLint numConfigs;
    EGLConfig config;

    display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

    eglInitialize(display, NULL, NULL);

    /* Here, the application chooses the configuration it desires. In this
     * sample, we have a very simplified selection process, where we pick
     * the first EGLConfig that matches our criteria */
    eglChooseConfig(display, attribs, &config, 1, &numConfigs);

    /* EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID is an attribute of the EGLConfig that is
     * guaranteed to be accepted by ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry().
     * As soon as we picked a EGLConfig, we can safely reconfigure the
     * ANativeWindow buffers to match, using EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID. */
    eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format);

    ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(appState->window, 0, 0, format);

    drawingSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, appState->window,
            NULL);

    EGLint contextAttribs[] =
    { EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL_NONE };
    context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, contextAttribs);

    eglMakeCurrent(display, drawingSurface, drawingSurface, context);

    eglQuerySurface(display, drawingSurface, EGL_WIDTH, &width);
    eglQuerySurface(display, drawingSurface, EGL_HEIGHT, &height);

    this->SetProjectionMatrix();
    this->SetCameraTransform();

    for (ShaderVectorIterator iter = shaders.begin(); iter != shaders.end();
            ++iter)
    {
        Shader* pCurrent = *iter;
        pCurrent->Link();
    }

    initialized = true;
}

void Renderer::Draw(Renderable* pRenderable)
{
    assert(pRenderable);
    if (pRenderable)
    {
        Geometry* pGeometry = pRenderable->GetGeometry();
        Shader* pShader = pRenderable->GetShader();
        assert(pShader && pGeometry);
        if (pShader && pGeometry)
        {
            pShader->Setup(pRenderable, cameraTransform, projectionMatrix);

            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, pGeometry->GetNumIndices(),
                    GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, pGeometry->GetIndexBuffer());
        }
    }
}

void Renderer::Update()
{
    if (initialized)
    {
        glClearColor(0.95f, 0.95f, 0.95f, 1);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        for (RenderableVectorIterator iter = renderables.begin();
                iter != renderables.end(); ++iter)
        {
            Renderable* pRenderable = *iter;
            if (pRenderable)
            {
                Draw(pRenderable);
            }
        }

                eglSwapBuffers(display, drawingSurface);
    }
}
```

TexturedRectangle.cpp (Which extends Rectangle.cpp)

```
TexturedRectangle::TexturedRectangle(int posX, int posY, int width, int height, Texture* texture)
    : Engine::Rectangle(posX, posY, width, height),
      texture(texture),
      textCords({0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f})
{
    shader = new TextureShader();

    auto texShader = (TextureShader*)shader;

    texShader->SetTexture(texture);

    SetShader(texShader);

    GetGeometry()->SetTextureCoordinates(&textCords);
    GetGeometry()->SetTexStride(sizeof(float) * 2);
    GetGeometry()->SetNumTexCoordElements(2);

}
```

Rectangle.cpp (`verts` is `float verts[8]` and contains a list of rectangle relative coordinates)

```
 Rectangle::Rectangle(int posX, int posY, int width, int height) :
            verts(), 
        indices( { 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1 }), 
        colors( { 0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 1.0,
                0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 1.0, 
                0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 1.0, 
                0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 1.0, 
                0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 1.0, 
                0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 1.0, }),
                shader(new OrthoGraphicShader())
    {
        float leftX = 0 - (width / 2.f);
        float rightX = width / 2.f;
        float upperY = 0 - (height / 2.f);
        float lowerY = height / 2.f;

        verts[0] = leftX;
        verts[1] = upperY;
        verts[2] = rightX;
        verts[3] = upperY;
        verts[4] = leftX;
        verts[5] = lowerY;
        verts[6] = rightX;
        verts[7] = lowerY;

        this->SetGeometry(&geometry);
        this->SetShader(shader);
        this->SetTransform(&transform);

        this->Translate(posX, posY);

        geometry.SetVertexBuffer(verts);
        geometry.SetNumVertices(4);
        geometry.SetIndexBuffer(indices);
        geometry.SetNumIndices(6);
        geometry.SetName("quad");
        geometry.SetNumVertexPositionElements(2);
        geometry.SetVertexStride(sizeof(float) * 2);
        geometry.SetColor(colors);

    }
```

Because of the inheritance between Rectangle and TexturedRectangle `colors` is never used. Yes I know it's ugly, and I'm planning to clean up the whole inheritance model soon.

Does anyone have any idea why the texture is being drawn completely black? I've been looking at this code all day, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: That is quite a lot of code for a Q&A site, I'd say you need to isolate your problem a bit more. Are your textures a power of 2? What happens if you fill them with FFFFFF (white) bytes?

Comment: The texture is a power of two (256x256). Filling the image data with `(char)255` changes nothing. I am aware of the fact that it is a lot of code. But I have no idea where the problem is. I assume that the fragment shader is correct. Because changing it to `gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1)` results in a red square. And since lodepng returns the correct dimensions I'm pretty sure that the `unsigned char image[]` contains the correct bytes. But since this is my first OpenGL-ES C++ project I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out what the problem is. I was calling Texture::Init(), which sets up the texture data, before the Renderer created an OpenGL context.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, headerData.width, headerData.height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
```

Creating the context is done by this line:

```
context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, contextAttribs);
```